# difficulty in passing dynamic value to onClick method

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

```
<a href="Variables.createURL" OnClick='getURI('<%=variables.createURL>');'></a>
```

When i try to pass dynamic value to OnClick method, am getting an Exception

```
Illegal character in string <
```

what would be the mistake that am doing here,

Comment: You're closing the single quote too soon - you need to use `OnClick='getURI("<%=variables.createURL%>");'`

Comment: yes illegeal character, Syntax should be <%=variables.createURL **%>**

Answer (score 0):

Change to `<a href="Variables.createURL" OnClick='getURI('<%=variables.createURL%>');'></a>`.
You forgot "`%`" after `createURL`.

Comment: This time Error is "Unexpected token '<' inside tag <a>"

Comment: Change '<%=variables.createURL%>');' to double quotes "<%=variables.createURL%>"